# esxi and server 2008 on the same physical server

Tags: windows-server-2008

I want to use the same physical server to use esxi 4 and server 2008 or 2012.
How can we proceed with this installation? The physical server has 2 hard drives in raid1. Which OS must be first installed?

Comment: You want to dual boot ESXi and Windows Server 2008? Why not install ESXi and then install Server 2008 in a VM. Or just install Server 2008 and use Hyper-V?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve - how do you want to use the systems, are you expecting them both to be available at the same time ?

Comment: Why ESXi 4? 5 was released, what, 2 years ago or so?

Answer (score 10):

This is stupid, please don't do it. It makes no sense whatsoever, and will be almost certainly more hassle than it's worth.

Comment: is esxi  work separatly the performance of all vm will be very good than windows 2008

Comment: "please don't it"

Comment: @bouh yes, it will. abou 2% to 3% - that is the overhead compared to running ONE vm in ESXI alone. Install ESXI, boot a Server 2008 (better: 2012, unless you love software 2 generations back) virtual machine.

Comment: Thx Tom,I will try it

Answer (score 5):

You want to install ESXi 4, and then create a Windows VM on the ESXi host. It makes absolutely no sense to dual boot.

Also, ESXi 4 is relatively old now. If you're just using ESXi with no licensed features, I suggest going with the latest version: [ESXi 5.1](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/info/slug/datacenter_cloud_infrastructure/vmware_vsphere/5_1)

Comment: He seems to love old stuff. He also talks of Server 2008, which is 2 generations back.

Answer (score 1):

The only possible way to make this work is to ditch the RAID configuration so you have two independent disks.

Install Server 2008 in the first disk.  Remove that disk and install ESX 4 on the 2nd disk.  Add the Server 2008 disk back into the machine and boot it up.